# Self fixed issue on own bounty question

Tags: discussion

I want to ask how should I behave in this situation? I have [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588510/cannot-connect-to-vpn-with-openvpn-in-ubuntu-14-04/591852?noredirect=1#comment825373_591852) that I asked and put bounty on as I couldn't figure it out what was going on. I was getting help to it but it turned out I solved the issue myself by completely replacing its data and context, script etc. As the OP data placed in my question turned out to be wack, wrong and needed complete re-edition.

So, should I put the different solution I did to solve this issue? And how should I behave to bounty on this question?

Comment: The reputation is lost anyway, so you can ignore that. Post your answer, please!

Comment: ok thanks, I got it.

Comment: @user300458 doesn’t work like that anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Answer it where you also point out what went wrong with the data in the question. Don't edit the question correcting the mistakes in the question though. Create the answer as if you are answering someone else.
- What you do with the bounty is up to you. Don't award it, award it. Whatever feels right to you.

Comment: You can manually share the bounty bonus between answers? That's new to me.

Comment: ok I understand it now clear.

Answer (score 0):

Write how you did solve your problem as answer to your own question and accept it.

You can not get the bounty back or award it to yourself, though. So if you think one of the other posts did help you to get to the right solution and don't want to waste the 50 rep points, I would award them to that answer. Otherwise they will vanish. Except if some answers have votes of +2 at least, half of the bonus will be shared among those.

Comment: thanks both answers provided here help enough.