# On my question (with bounty) mine is the only answer. Should I just accept my own answer or let the bounty continue to expire?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty

I asked a question. After further searching and no answers I set a bounty.

Only after that did I happen upon information I needed by a total fluke. As a result I have posted an answer that addresses my specific instance although it does not necessarily address the needs of others who might want to know "how to": [how do I "rebuild" or "repair" APTD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598525/how-do-i-rebuild-or-repair-aptd)

I understand that the 50 rep is gone and that was expected (although it would be a shame if it evaporated into the ether) but what is the best thing to do in this instance? Should I accept my own answer? Can I extend the bounty period? Or do I just shrug, chalk it up to experience, and leave it at that?

Comment: similar http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13651/self-fixed-issue-on-own-bounty-question

Answer (score 5):

Shrug. Basically, since you can't award the bounty to yourself, the best thing to do is just let the bounty expire. If anyone happens to post a better ansser than yours in the time remaining, give them the bounty. Even if it is not as good as yours, if it is good enough, you may as well award the bounty. You can't get it back so you might as well give it to the most deserving answer.

Note that awarding a bounty is not linked to accepting an answer. You can accept one answer and award the bounty to another. So, you could also accept yours and still be able to give the bounty if anyone else comes along.

Finally, remember that if you don't award the bounty manually, [half of it](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) will automatically go to the highest voted answer (as long as that is not your own):

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2. If no new answer matches this requirement, no reputation will be awarded at all, and the reputation used on the bounty will be lost forever.

So, yes, shrug and chalk it up to experience.